# Reading Value from Text file to set in batch file variable

Tags: batch-file

```
@echo off
reg query HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Candle\KNT\Ver610\Primary\Environment\ >nul
if %ERRORLEVEL% EQU 0 (
    echo "Key is added into 32 bit"
    cd /d "%CANDLE_HOME%\logs" & (for /f "tokens=1,2 delims=|" %%a in (Account_Detail.txt) do set "value1=%%a"&set "value2=%%b") & cmd /v:on /c "(echo Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00& echo [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Candle\KNT\Ver610\Primary\Environment]& echo "CT_CMSTEST"="IP.SPIPE:#!value1!;IP.SPIPE:#!value2!")>ntenv.reg" & reg import ntenv.reg
) else (
    echo "Key is added into 64 bit"
    cd /d "%CANDLE_HOME%\logs" & (for /f "tokens=1,* delims=|" %%a in (Account_Detail.txt) do set "value1=%%a"&set "value2=%%b") & cmd /v:on /c "(echo Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00& echo [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Candle\KNT\Ver610\Primary\Environment]& echo "CT_CMSTEST"="IP.SPIPE:#!value1!;IP.SPIPE:#!value2!")>ntenv.reg" & reg import ntenv.reg
    if EXIST %candle_home%\TMAITM6\kntcma.ini (
        echo CTIRA_SUBSYSTEM_ID=>>C:\IBM\ITM\TMAITM6\kntcma.ini
        cd /d "%CANDLE_HOME%\logs" & (for /f "tokens=3,* delims=|" %%a in (Account_Detail.txt) do set "value3=%%a") & cmd /v:on /C "(echo CTIRA_HOSTNAME=%value3%_%computername%     .TYPE=REG_EXPAND_SZ>>C:\IBM\ITM\TMAITM6\kntcma.ini) else (
        echo CTIRA_SUBSYSTEM_ID=>>C:\IBM\ITM\TMAITM6_x64\kntcma.ini
        cd /d "%CANDLE_HOME%\logs" & (for /f "tokens=3,* delims=|" %%a in (Account_Detail.txt) do set "value3=%%a") & cmd /v:on /C "(echo CTIRA_HOSTNAME=%value3%_%computername%     .TYPE=REG_EXPAND_SZ>>C:\IBM\ITM\TMAITM6_x64\kntcma.ini))
```

Please help me here...I have changed but not able to execute...Is there any character limit to execute that command..Separetly both command are running.

```
cd /d "%CANDLE_HOME%\logs" & (for /f "tokens=3,* delims=|" %%a in (Account_Detail.txt) do set "value3=%%a") & cmd /v:on /C "(echo CTIRA_HOSTNAME=%value3%_%computername%     .TYPE=REG_EXPAND_SZ>>C:\IBM\ITM\TMAITM6\kntcma.ini
```

Please help me on this.

Comment: Is it a problem to use several lines in a batch file?

Comment: echo ABC=%value3%_.TYPE=REG_EXPAND_SZ>>C:\IBM\ITM\TMAITM6\kntcma.ini........This one(value3) also to be passed...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Place `file.txt` in the same `logs` folder with two text items inside separated by a pipe:

```
192.168.1.1|192.168.1.2
```

and then this should work:

```
cd /d "%CANDLE_HOME%\logs" & (for /f "tokens=1,* delims=|" %%a in (file.txt) do set "value1=%%a"&set "value2=%%b") & cmd /v:on /c "(echo Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00& echo [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Candle\KNT\Ver610\Primary\Environment]& echo "CT_CMSTEST"="IP.SPIPE:#!value1!;IP.SPIPE:#!value2!")>ntenv.reg" & reg import ntenv.reg
```

Answer (score 0):

what about the command line arguments?

```
cd %CANDLE_HOME%\logs 
set "value1=%~1"
set "value2=%~2"
(echo Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00 
 echo [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Candle\KNT\Ver610\Primary\Environment] 
 echo "CT_CMSTEST"="IP.SPIPE:#%value1%;IP.SPIPE:#%value2%"
 )>ntenv.reg 
 reg import ntenv.reg
```

and just call it like `my_bat.bat my_value1 my_value2`  ?

or you can just a preset values with `set "value1=my_value"..`

Comment: used the same... and call my_bat.bat 10.95.34.36 29.43.122.30

Comment: used the same... and call my_bat.bat 10.95.34.36 29.43.122.30...but getting the error accessing the registry.